# AppSync and GraphQL Enum mutations

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have the following schema in AppSync for GraphQL

```
input CreateTeamInput {
    name: String!
    sport: Sports!
    createdAt: String
}

enum Sports {
    baseball
    basketball
    cross_country
}
type Mutation{
    createTeam(input: CreateTeamInput!): Team
}
```

However when I try to execute the query using AWS Amplify library via

```
export const CreateTeam = `mutation CreateTeam($name: String!, $sport: String!){
  createTeam(input:{name:$name, sport:$sport}) {
    id,
    name,
    sport
  }
}
`;

....

API.graphql(graphqlOperation(CreateTeam, this.state))
```

I get the following error: `Validation error of type VariableTypeMismatch: Variable type doesn't match`.

How can I update my code to work with this enum type?

Comment: Can you provide your mutation definition? We don't know here what the createTeam mutation expects

Comment: @VasileiosLekakis post has been updated with the mutation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CreateTeamInput.sport` field type is an enum, hence your `$sport` variable must be an enum.

Try changing your query to:

```
export const CreateTeam = `mutation CreateTeam($name: String!, $sport: Sports!){
  createTeam(input:{name:$name, sport:$sport}) {
    id,
    name,
    sport
  }
};
```

**Note:**
As a convention, prefer using uppercase for your enum values so it's easy to tell them apart from strings.

```
enum SPORTS {
    BASEBALL
    BASKETBALL
    CROSS_COUNTRY
}
```

Comment: Well this was a brain fart on my part.  I was under the assumption since the schema type of "Sports" existed just on my graphql server, that the client query would have idea what to do with `$sports: Sports!`, but it worked just fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$sport needs to be a Sports type not a String

Comment: How do I actually specify a Sports type though?  I was able to create it no problem in my schema.graphql file used on the server side (in the code snippet above enum Sports{...}), but how do I create it from a client request?

Comment: I couldn't add a comment on multiple lines so I created an answer above. @DanRamos